# Finding buffer-overflow code vulnerability

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am exploiting a vulnerability given in [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/26889/).

The exploit works perfectly but I want to find out the code causing the vulnerabilities it is a RET overwrite base attack the RET address is being overwritten to the shell code. I want to know that vulnerable function epilog and prelog.

Answer (score 0):

Return addresses are generally overwritten in stack based buffer overflows where the data copied into a buffer exceeds the allocated buffer space and corrupts/overwrites a stack frame, including the return address (future EIP).